# Using regular libgdx shapes with box2d shapes

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Before I decided that I wanted to use box2d for all my game physics, I had set up all the non-animated shapes using shaperenderer. I have converted my box2d world and shape to meters at a scale of 32 ppm but all my regular shapes are still drawn with pixels.

Since my box2d circle has been scaled along with the camera, it renders fine with the right size. However, all the shapes that I drew with pixels using shaperenderer are way out of view.

1. Do I need to redo all of my original shapes with box2d shapes?
2. Can I just scale all the original shapes with my PPM scaling?

From what I understand, I should be able to just scale all the dimensions of the original shapes by the PPM since I have already scaled the camera?

```
public class Controller extends Game {
    public OrthographicCamera cam;
    public ShapeRenderer shape;
    public ShapeRenderer circle;
    public FitViewport viewport;
    public Stage stage;

    public World world;
    public Body ball;
    public Box2DDebugRenderer box2DDebugRenderer;

  @Override
  public void create() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), cam);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    shape = new ShapeRenderer();
    circle = new ShapeRenderer(); //balls shot from cannon

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
    box2DDebugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
    //setScreen(new TitleScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    shape.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    circle.dispose();
    box2DDebugRenderer.dispose();
    world.dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}

public Body createBall(){
    Body bBody;
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.position.set(500,500);
    def.fixedRotation = true;
    bBody = world.createBody(def);

    return bBody;
}
}
```

And here is is the actual game screen that implements all the original shapes and the box2d shapes:

```
import static com.mygdx.game.Utils.Constants.PPM;

public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
Controller game;

//x-axis length for top/bottom bar
private float goalWidth;

//y-axis height for back bar
private float goalHeight;
private float goalPostThickness;

//Screen height and width
private float screenWidth;
private float screenHeight;

//How far down/up posts are from edge of screen
private float goalPostTopOffset;
private float goalPostBottomOffset;

private float cannonOriginX; //Variables used for starting position of balls
private float cannonOriginY;

float ballX;
float ballY;

public GameScreen (Controller game){
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void show(){
    game.ball = game.createBall();
    // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(32/2/PPM);

// Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f; // Make it bounce a little bit

// Create our fixture and attach it to the body
    Fixture fixture = game.ball.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    circle.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta){
    //Logic
    screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    goalPostTopOffset = screenHeight/7;
    goalPostBottomOffset = goalPostTopOffset * 3;
    goalHeight = screenHeight - (goalPostTopOffset + goalPostBottomOffset);
    goalWidth = screenWidth / 6;
    goalPostThickness = screenWidth / 75;

    cannonOriginX = goalWidth / 2; //Variables used for starting position of balls
    cannonOriginY = (goalPostThickness*5) / 2;

    ballX = 0 + cannonOriginX;
    ballY = (goalPostBottomOffset - (goalPostBottomOffset / 4)) + cannonOriginY;

    game.world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

    //Draw
    game.cam.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.box2DDebugRenderer.render(game.world, game.cam.combined.scl(PPM));
    game.shape.setProjectionMatrix(game.cam.combined);

    drawNonAnimated();
    drawAnimated();



}

@Override
public void hide(){

}

//draws stationary objects such as goal posts
public void drawNonAnimated(){
    //Top goal bar
    game.shape.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    game.shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    game.shape.rect(screenWidth - goalWidth, screenHeight - goalPostTopOffset, goalWidth, goalPostThickness);
    game.shape.end();

    //Bottom goal bar
    game.shape.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    game.shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    game.shape.rect(screenWidth - goalWidth, goalPostBottomOffset, goalWidth, goalPostThickness);
    game.shape.end();

    //Back goal bar
    game.shape.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    game.shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    game.shape.rect(screenWidth - goalPostThickness, goalPostBottomOffset, goalPostThickness, goalHeight);
    game.shape.end();

    //Cannon platform
    game.shape.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    game.shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    game.shape.rect(0, goalPostBottomOffset - (goalPostBottomOffset / 4),goalWidth, goalPostThickness*2);
    game.shape.end();

    //Cannon
    game.shape.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    game.shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    game.shape.rect(0, goalPostBottomOffset - (goalPostBottomOffset / 4), cannonOriginX,
            cannonOriginY, goalWidth, goalPostThickness*5, 1, 1, 45);
    game.shape.end();
}

public void drawAnimated(){
    //Ball(s)
        game.circle.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        game.circle.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        game.circle.circle(ballX, ballY, goalPostThickness * 2.5f);
        game.circle.end();
        game.cam.update();

        ballX += 1;
}



}
```

As I mentioned earlier, the circle shape rendered with box2d shows fine with the PPM scale. However, all the shapes that I drew with shaperenderer are off the screen.

Comment: I'm not going to answer your question because I'm not experienced with box2d, but I will recommend that you don't worry about scaling everything to the screen size. I recommend that you put everything you want to render on a stage, then use an ExtendsViewport so you never have to worry about scaling because that Viewport will always have either the same height, or the same width. If you use a FitViewport, I believe that it will always render the same thing no matter what the resolution is. There are many Viewports you can use to make it easier for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the fitviewport but was still having scaling problems. The viewport solved issues with different aspect ratio beween devises but objects in my game were still rendering to big/too small. This was a problem since the game would become very easy/hard with different sized objects. Not sure if it shouldn't be that way and I just did something wrong.

Comment: One possibility is Constants.PPM. If that varies somehow, that could be a problem. (If it's public static final then it should be ok). Another thing you do is use the screen height and screen width to determine dimensions and other things. You could try doing that another way such as using a bounding box that doesn't change or use width and height constants that you pass to your ExtendsViewport. The trick is to never use Gdx.graphics.getWidth() or getHeight() for things other than UIs or something that doesn't affect gameplay.

Comment: Also, if you use a stage, you shouldn't have to store an instance of your camera or of your viewport. You can always do stage.getViewport().getCamera() if you need it.